# how to make slideshow images clickable to open an image on same page using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using an image slider that supports swipe, and I want to open other images at the bottom of the same page, when I click on any of the image in the slider. Here's my piece of code, that is not enabling me to do so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Demo 1</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<link href="ninja-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script language="javascript" 
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script src="ninja-slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.hidable').hide();

        $('.imgbtn').click(function(){
            target = $(this).attr('data-target');
            $(".link:nth-child(" + target + ")").click();
        });

        $('.link').each(function(){

            $(this).toggleClass("active").next();
            $(this).click(function(){
                var show=$(this).attr('rel');
                $('.hidable').slideUp('slow');
                $(show).slideDown('fast');
            });

        });
    });

   </script>
    <style>
    body {font: normal 0.9em Arial;margin:0;}
    a {color:#fc006d;}
    ul li {padding: 10px 0;}
    header {display:block;padding:60px 0 10px;background-color:#ff005d;text-
     align:center;}
    header a {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 24px;
        line-height: 24px;
        padding: 8px 13px 7px;
        color: #4d5256;
        text-decoration:none;
        transition: color 0.7s;
    }

     </style>
     </head>
      <body>

    <div id="ninja-slider">
    <div class="slider-inner">
        <ul>
            <li> 
                <img src="pic1.png" class="ns-img"><a class='link' 
     rel='#div1'  href="#"> </a></img>

            </li>
            <li><img src="pic2.png" class="ns-img"><a class='link' 
     rel='#div2' href="#"></a></img>

            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="pic3.png" class="ns-img"><a class='link' 
     rel='#div3' href="#"></a></img>

            </li>
            <li>
               <img src="pic4.png" class="ns-img"><a class='link' 
      rel='#div4' href="#"></a></img>

            </li>
             <li>
                <img src="pic5.png" class="ns-img"><a class='link' 
      rel='#div5' href="#"></a></img>

            </li>
        </ul>

     </div>
     <div id="boxes">
     <div class='hidable' id='div1'><table><tr><td><img class='link' 
    src="icon1.png"></a></td></tr></table></div>
    <div class='hidable' id='div2'><table><tr><td><img src="icon2.png"></a>
  </td></tr></table></div>
     <div class='hidable' id='div3'><table><tr><td><img src="icon3.png"></a>
  </td></tr></table></div>
   <div class='hidable' id='div4'><table><tr><td><img src="icon4.png"></a>
   </td></tr></table></div>
    <div class='hidable' id='div5'><table><tr><td><img  src="icon5.png"></a>
    </td></tr></table></div>

   </div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: if _ninja-slider.js_ is dependent on jQuery, then load the slider after it

Comment: Hey, thanks but I didn't get it. :(

Comment: The images `icon1.png - icon5.png` all have the same id. That is not allowed in html and could lead to unpredictable results.

Comment: Changed them, not working. :(

Answer (score 0):

in my case this worked:
`<li><a href="00001.jpg"><img class="ns-img" src="00001.jpg" style="cursor-pointer;"></a></li>`
So the -Tag has to be inside the ...

Small problem: all pictures have to be of the same aspect ratio.
I didn´t try to fix this, but generated the pictures to fit...

regards, JB

Link to the same topic at the Ninja-Slider-page:
[Menucool NinjaSlider FAQ](http://www.menucool.com/5880/Need-links-inside-ninja-slider)